# JOOQ generate with composite key with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I'm trying JOOQ to generate the database schema to use it with spring-boot.
I'm using the following maven configuration:

```
<!-- Generator parameters -->
<generator>
    <!-- The default code generator. You can override this one, to generate your own code style
         Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator -->
    <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>

    <!-- The naming strategy used for class and field names.
         You may override this with your custom naming strategy. Some examples follow
         Defaults to org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy -->

    <database>
        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
        <!--<name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>-->
        <includes>.*</includes>
        <excludes></excludes>
        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
    </database>
    <target>
        <packageName>org.jooq.codegen.maven.engletter</packageName>
        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>

    </target>
    <generate>
        <javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>
        <validationAnnotations>true</validationAnnotations>
        <springAnnotations>true</springAnnotations>
        <pojosToString>true</pojosToString>
        <jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>
    </generate>
    <strategy>
        <name>org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy</name>
        <matchers>
            <tables>
                <table>
                    <recordImplements>ch.rsmch.backend.data.entity.TblEntity</recordImplements>
                </table>
            </tables>
        </matchers>
    </strategy>
</generator>
```

This works well for entities with single keys. It produces code like this for the table tbladdservice:

```
/**
 * Getter for <code>public.tbladdservice.id</code>. key
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 64)
public Long getId() {
    return (Long) get(0);
}
```

But for tables with a composite key (tbladdservicecon it is called), it only generates:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Primary key information
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public Record2<Long, Long> key() {
    return (Record2) super.key();
}
```

The problem with this (as far as I understand): The @Id is missing.
If I 'm calling

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I'm getting this error (and the application won't start):

```
CreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: org.jooq.codegen.maven.engletter.tables.records.TbladdserviceconRecord
```

Is there a way to convince JOOQ to generate the @Id statement?

Many thanks for any help.

To make this clearer:
I have a PostgreSQL schema with 35 entities, some of them created as connectors to break up m:m relations like in the tables here:

[Tables used here, in detail tbladdservicecon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8hyn.png)

JOOQ generates everything correct, but with the connection entities it does not work to make it clear to Spring what the key is.

As this problem stops the appication with the error above, I can't use JOOQ with Spring. I'm not even using this enitity until now (but will use it later). Or is there a way to go around this error?

Comment: This is because a `RecordN[...]` type is not a good fit for a JPA `@Id` value. Things do get tricky with JPA when using composite keys, in general. What's your expectation here? What would you use the generated class for?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I added a part of my ER-diagram to clarify the question. I hope this helps to explain my problem.

Comment: What I meant is: Why do you need the `@Id` annotation present on that class? Are you using jOOQ-generated classes as entities? They're not designed for this purpose...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was looking for a way to generate entities. Then I did not understand it correctly. But why is it possible to generate Spring annotations if this is not designed for that? Sorry, I'm quite new to Spring and have to use a template (from Vaadin). I would prefer to use only JOOQ but I'm not sure I'm able to get rid of Spring.

Comment: Hi Lukas. Thank you for your answer. I now write my own entity for every table. I would have preferred JOOQ and use its generation. But then I will do it manually and use JOOQ as a template. I could answer this now myself, but how can I credit your answer and accept it?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, didn't see your previous comment. Hmm, there seems to be some confusion about the purpose of jOOQ, Spring, and JPA, each. I can't explain the difference in a single comment :) but the three APIs solve different problems, so while using only jOOQ is definitely possible, Spring can still add value to your project. Feel free to write your own answer (thanks for doing that, it's very helpful for future visitors!) If you want to give me credit, you can just point to the comments from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered by Lukas Eder (see comments):

1. It is possible to generate POJO's with JOOQ, but the outcome is not thought as input for JPA.
2. The idea is to use them both (and also Spring) as needed but not to use one and mix it with an other.

Hints for a good combination of JOOQ and Hibernate are given by Thorben Janssen in his excellent Thoughts on Java:
[Hibernate & jOOQ – A Match Made in Heaven](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-jooq-a-match-made-in-heaven/) .